# Show div and hold it when hover on image

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry for the bad title, don't realy know how te explain it in that short.

Well I have a `img`, when I hover it it shows a div with some text.
That div appears in the `img` you were hoverd in, and when you hover that div...
You exualy leave the `img` so the div with the text dissapear.

So what my question realy is, is how can I let it still display it as block?

I already tried something;

The jQuery part;

```
$("img#hover-for-text").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).next().stop().fadeIn();
});
$("#text-hold").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).next().stop().fadeIn();
});

$("img#hover-for-text").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).next().stop().fadeOut();
});
```

The HTML part;

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <img src="images/projects/<?=$data['picture']?>" class="img-responsive" id="hover-for-text">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <a style="color:black;"><?=$data['content']?></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS part;

```
.carousel-caption {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: can't you bind the events on the `.slide`?

Comment: What do you mena @JoelAlmeida ?

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jAlmeida/7f2qt986/

Comment: gonna add as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the events to the `.slide` div and work with the children of it, so the mouse never leaves the parent div.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slide").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).find(".carousel-caption").stop().fadeIn();
    });

    $(".slide").on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).find(".carousel-caption").stop().fadeOut();
    });

})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jAlmeida/7f2qt986/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting mouse over for the image you have to put mouse over for the parent component

```
$("#mycarousel").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(".carousel-caption",this).stop().fadeIn();
});

$("#mycarousel").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(".carousel-caption",this).stop().fadeOut();
});
```

will be better choice

Here the ",this" will allow you to select "carousel-caption" only the currently focused carousel

Check http://jsfiddle.net/ZigmaEmpire/6a18txbu/1/

In case your #mycarousel is the parent most then introduce another div inside it and write mouse event for it with class name instead of id

Comment: This works well too. but I give the reputations to Joel Almeida, he was first :s